# C : dev C++, stopped working error, code to create node in linked list

Tags: c, list, linked-list, insert

while making Link ADT, i got error compiling test.c (main code to test functions)
i think the problem is from function pushFront.

i tryed many ways to get rid of the error but error message doesnt change. there's no error when compiling header file, and main c file without pushfront.

Please help me.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "ListADT.h"

int main()
{
LIST* LIST=createList();
char* data ;
NODE* NODE=createNode(data);

pushFront(LIST, data);

return;
}
```

Here is the test.c file that makes error.
when i compile this file, "test.exe stopped working"
actually i dont know the exact message inenglish because i run programm in my langauge.

below are, struct defining NODE and LIST.

```
//List ADT Type Defintions
typedef struct node
{
    void* dataPtr;
    struct node* link;
} NODE;

typedef struct
{
    int count;
    NODE* pos;
    NODE* head;
    NODE* rear;
} LIST;
```

below are some of functions in headerfile ListADT.h that i am testing.
i think the source of error is pushfront.

```
//=================CreatNode======================
NODE* createNode(void* dataInPtr)
{
    NODE* NewNode;
    NewNode = (NODE*) malloc (sizeof (NODE));

    NewNode->dataPtr = dataInPtr; 
    NewNode->link=NULL;
}

//========insert a new node to the front of the list===========
void pushFront (LIST* pList, void* dataInPtr)
{
    NODE* NewNode;

    NewNode = createNode(dataInPtr); 

    if(pList->count==0)
    {
        pList->head = NewNode;
        pList->rear = NewNode;
    }
    else
    {
        NewNode->link = pList->head;
        pList->head = NewNode;  
    }
    pList->count++; 
}
```

i am really not good at coding and i think the matter is might be very trivial. but i cannot find it.
Please help me.

Comment: the error is "stopped working" while compiling

Comment: Make that clear in your question and don't comment.

Comment: Where excactly do you get which error message when you do what ?

Comment: `createNode` should `return NewNode;`

Comment: sorry! i was finding adjusting question...

Comment: thank you so much @BLUEPIXY it was so trivial but big mistake thank you

Comment: learn to debug  ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NODE *node=createNode(data);
LIST *list=createList();
pushFront(list, data);
```

and do return NewNode in  createNode()